# split a file by a line prefix

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

My data looks like this:

```
60  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
61  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
62  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
63  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
64  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to split it out into separate files by the line prefix.. like this:

```
file 60 contains all lines prefixed with "60"
file 61 contains all lines prefixed with "61"
...
```

The best idea I came up with so far was to grep for all the line prefixes, then loop through that and grep each one of them out into a separate file, but it's a fairly large file, so that might take a really long time.  Perhaps there is a better way than looping and grepping?   Some way of grep grouping?  I know there is a way to cut the file up if there were markers between each section like --- but I'm not entirely sure that's the best way either.

Comment: also, if there is some way to just do it in vim that's fine too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the input file is called `data`, one solution is:

```
awk '{print>$1}' data
```

In `awk`, the first field (column) is called `$1`.  The above  loops through each line of input (`awk` does this implicitly) and writes that line to a file whose name is the first field.

In more detail:

- The command is placed in braces.  Since there is no qualifier in front of the braces, the command will be run on every input line.
- The command `print`, with no argument, will print the whole input line.
- The symbol `>` indicates redirection of the output to a file
- The file name is specified as `$1` which, again, refers to whatever text was in the first field of the input line.

Thus, this command will create files named `60,` `61`, etc. which will contain the corresponding lines from the input file.

#### Handling very large datasets

By default, `awk` keeps all the files handles open until the whole command finishes.  Consequently, with very large datasets, it is possible to exceed the system limits on number of open files.  The simplest solution is to use append and close each file after writing:

```
awk '{print>>$1; close($1)}' data
```

Because this uses `>>` (append), this will add to existing data files rather than overwrite them.  If that isn't what you  want, delete them before running this command.

Comment: So in bash I would need to say >> to append to a file but in awk a single > will append?

Comment: @slf `awk` is not like `bash`.  In a single invocation of `awk`, such as the command above, the first use `>filename` will overwrite `filename`.  Any subsequent use of `>filename`, however, will _append_.  Thus, the above code `awk` should do what you want.  Use `>>` if you want always to append, keeping whatever was in the file before `awk` was run.

Comment: this is the same problem I was having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093626/split-file-using-awk  -- without a close(fd) then you run out of file handles

Comment: @slf Good point.  For handling large datasets, I added to the answer a version with `close`.

Comment: @l0b0 That sounds strange.  Awk does its processing line-by-line.  This script does not create any arrays or other data structure that could consume RAM.   While processing that much data may take time, I see no reason, in this case, for it to consume RAM.  Have you tried different versions of awk, say gawk or mawk, to see if results vary?

Comment: Sorry @John1024, my bad. Turns out a crap indexer (`tracker-miner`) was trying to index the files at the same time.

Comment: A couple of useful enhancements that took a bit of digging for me to figure out: `awk -F , '{print >> ("filename-prefix-" substr($1, 0, 7) ".suffix")}' input_file`

The `-F ,` allows adaptation to inputs that aren't space separated the way the OPs data is (e.g. CSV files), while string concatenation and the substr builtin allow for more control over the output filename.